# Are there reasons not to use ARIA states and roles as selectors in CSS?

Tags: html, css, wai-aria

I'm currently working on making an accessible site using, among other things, ARIA tags. It occurred to me that attributes such as `aria-invalid` would be good selectors for my CSS to target, rather than using a `.error` class.

The benefit of this is leaner, more meaningful HTML, which is easier for me to hook into from CSS (and JS). That said, I haven't seen this done elsewhere so I'm suspicious there are downsides to leveraging accessibility tags for styling. I suspect the use of unconstrained attribute selectors makes for less performant CSS, but are there other downsides I haven't considered?

Comment: Using ARIA tags in CSS selectors is recomended by W3C - https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accessiblewidget,  section 2.7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Attribute selectors are a very flexible way to manage styles for large-scale CSS because the attribute selectors will always have a [specificity of `0-0-1-0`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

`[aria-*]` selectors are perfectly fine to use as styling hooks, and I also recommend using custom `[data-*]` attributes to fill in the gaps where you might need a one-off. Certainly class selectors should continue to be used, however you can do some very elegant style extensions with attribute selectors:

```
[data-foo] {
    color: red;
}
[data-foo="bar"] {
    color: blue;
}
[data-foo="fizz"] {
    color: green;
}
```

Each of these selectors has the same specificity, and the cascade will allow the styles to be applied appropriately.

You could create your own form of classes by using the `[attr~="value"]` selector if need be.

Using the ["attribute contains" selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) can be useful for [a technique that I call "classy images"](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/classy-images-in-markdown)

---

One of the hidden benefits to using attributes over classes is a performance gain in JavaScript. Instead of having to check for the presence of a class on an element (which is remarkably easy to get wrong), browsers have supported `getAttribute`, `hasAttribute`, and `setAttribute` for a long time.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the JS performance implications, good point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that attributes like `aria-invalid` should be avoided in the first place. You should always use native semantics if available (e.g. `required` on input elements). This is called the [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#firstrule).

I think what you really want is to add styling to *computed* ARIA states and properties. Unfortunately this is not supported in CSS at the moment.

In summary: There is nothing wrong with using `[aria-invalid]` as a CSS-selector. It will just not help you much because you should avoid that attribute in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by **computed** states and properties?  ARIA attributes can be queried and set like any other HTML attribute and can be used as CSS selectors.  `#foo[aria-busy="true"]` is valid CSS, as is `div[aria-checked="false"]`

Comment: Example: `<input required value="">` and `<input aria-invalid="true">` are both invalid. One uses native semantics, the other one an ARIA attribute.

Comment: ok, but i don't follow what you mean by a **computed** ARIA attribute.  as mentioned, they're no different than other attributes and are perfectly fine to use in CSS selectors.  the `required` attribute is not an ARIA attribute.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about ARIA **states and properties**. They can be explicitly given using HTML attributes, but can also be implicit in native HTML semantics.

Comment: @tobib if you don't want the browser to handle your display of validation errors, then you can't use the `setCustomValidity` method on the inputs. In that case, `aria-invalid="true"` is useful for telling the browser that the input failed some JS check.